# Teradata Update query not giving required results

Tags: sql, teradata

Update ABC
Set typist_id = 'CW140'
where typist_id ='E85'

Above sql is not updating typist_id correctly.
SQL is running but result is not as  expected.
Am I doing any mistake?

Comment: What does *not updating typist_id correctly* mean? Does it return the correct row(s) when you run `select * from ABC where typist_id ='E85'`?

Comment: it gives 0 rows when I run select * from ABC where typist_id ='E85'.

Comment: Even on running select * from ABC where typist_id ='CW140' there is not output.

Comment: Well, apparently there's no row with that value in your table. What about `select * from ABC where typist_id LIKE 'E85%'`?

Comment: before update it was checked that there are 161 rows with typist_id  = 'E85' . The requirement is that I have to update them to CW140.

Comment: Then you didn't update to `'CW140'` but a different value, check your SQL history or DBQL.

Comment: I got the issue. The field to update was of char(3) due to which result was not as expected. thanks